# having problems with ActionListener java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

Getting an Error when i try to add a second Action Listener.
I have two different JButtons set up and have one of them working ok but when i try add a Action Listener for the second one i get the following error:

```
is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in     ActionListener
    next.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
```

and this is the code of the two Action Listeners.

```
    next.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
        public void preformedAction(ActionEvent e){

        }
    });

    close.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            frame.dispose();        //Closes Window
        }//End ActionPreformed
    });//End Of Close Action
```

the two buttons are "next" and "close"

Comment: try changing this line public void preformedAction(ActionEvent e){ to public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  and see

Comment: nope made no difference :(

Comment: first time i tried had spelling mistake it why through same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you need to override is `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`, not `preformedAciton(ActionEvent)`. The `ActionListener` you are creating and adding to `next` uses the latter method signature, which is incorrect, and thus the error.

Comment: hope you don't mind me asking but how exactly do i override it?? I'm kinda only a beginner to programming

Comment: @Dobby simply change preformedAction to actionPerformed